# Running test with jest command gives error

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mobx-react

I have setup the jest for my mobx project with following version

```
"jest": "^29.3.1",
"jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.3.1",
"jest-circus": "^29.3.1",
"jest-resolve": "^29.3.1",
"jest-watch-typeahead": "^2.2.1",
```

and mobx version is

```
    "mobx": "5.13.0",
    "mobx-react": "5.4.4",
    "mobx-react-devtools": "6.0.3",
    "mobx-react-lite": "1.4.1",
    "mobx-react-router": "4.0.7",
    "mobx-utils": "5.4.1",
```

but when i try to run default test with command jest it gives error as in image [image]

So my paths given in App.tsx are not working after jest setup, so here what could be the issue and how can we fix it.

Answer (score 0):

in you `package.json`, under `"jest":`  try to add  `"moduleDirectories"`

```
"moduleDirectories": ["node_modules", "bower_components", "src"],
```